# How does letting securities mature, without reinvesting the proceeds, contract the money supply?

Tags: federal-reserve

I am quoting [Sheila Bair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheila_Bair), who was Chair of the Federal Deposit Insurance Corporation from June 26 2006 to July 8 2011. ["Bair received a bachelor's degree from the University of Kansas and a J.D. from the University of Kansas School of Law."](https://abawtp.law.stanford.edu/exhibits/show/sheila-c-bair/biography) Bair does not appear to have any degrees in economics or finance.

Anyways, what does Bair mean by "**them**"? What kind of securities? Bonds?

From [IB Economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IB_Group_3_subjects), I know that a central bank can contract the money supply by selling bonds. But "**lets them mature without reinvesting the proceeds**"??? IB Economics didn't cover this tool! If a central bank "lets them mature", then the central bank shall simply recoup the par value of the bond, correct? Then "**without reinvesting the proceeds**", what does the central bank do with the par value?

> [In contrast, to take money out of the system, the Fed simply sells some of its securities or **lets them mature without reinvesting the proceeds**. This leads to higher rates, as private investors become more dominant in markets from which the Fed is withdrawing. Importantly, the markets, not the government, drive the rate increases. This avoids the unseemly appearance and excessive cost of the Fed essentially paying institutions not to lend.](https://www.ft.com/content/b82082c9-d26a-47a5-8b1a-34121f572645)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically answered it yourself. A central bank (CB) that is buying securities increases the money supply. The CB creates money and give it to the seller. The seller of the security now holds money (instead of a security/bond) that did not exits before in the system. The CB in turn holds the bond.

If the CB wants to reduce money supply, it can sell the bond, receive cash, which it simply "destroys" / "uncreates".

However, if one keeps **them** (securities/bonds) until maturity, one receives the notional back, which, unless the CB busy something else has a similar effect on money supply as selling the bond outright.

If one has a degree in finance or economics is mostly unimportant. In fact, some of the best never read finance or economics at university  (Charly Munger -law and meteorology, James Simons - math, Christine Lagarde -law, ...).